# How do I allow Dropbox read access from only a specific folder?

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm currently using the Dropbox [Chooser API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android) since it's easy to implement; but I would like it to be able to view only a single folder, not the entire Dropbox library. How do I do that?

Comment: as far as I know, its not possible.

Comment: That's correct, the Dropbox API does not currently offer the ability to restrict the path in their Dropbox that the user can choose from.

Comment: @Greg so none of the API will work? My intention is to share a public folder in a single account with many users.

Comment: The Chooser isn't built for sharing your own account. The Chooser will always show the account of whoever is logged in. That is, each user will see their own account, in order to pick from their own files to send to your app. If you want to share items from your own account, you may be interested in the shared link functionality: https://www.dropbox.com/help/274 or for a more advanced integration, the Core API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core